# Help in locating a portrait of Göttingen's faculty in 1899

Tags: reference-request, gottingen

Does anybody here own a copy of the poster "Mathematische Gesellschaft: Group Portrait - University of Göttingen (1899)" that Springer Verlag published in 1985? If so, would you be so kind as to share a photograph of it with me?

In case you don't own the poster but you know of a book in which I can find the group portrait in the poster, would you be so kind as to enter the relevant bibliographical information in an answer?

Let me thank you in advance for your attention and support.

Comment: Does it have to be the group portrait from 1899 specifically? There is another one from 1902, for example.

Comment: I could also come in handy... Does Max Dehn appear in that portrait? Thanks a bunch for your comment!

Comment: If you are actually looking for the portrait of a particular mathematician rather than a group portrait that includes them, it would be advantageous to state that in the question (avoids XY-problems). The 1902 portrait shows the names of the people in the picture at the bottom, but the image in Google's preview is too small to decipher them. You can do a Google image search for `Göttingen Mathematische Gesellschaft 1902` to check if you fare any better. The group portrait appears to have been used for the front cover of an AMS publication, and seems to be available from Alamy (for a fee).

Comment: I don't think Dehn is in the 1902 group portrait. By comparing the *length* of the names written underneath the photograph (I can recognize Hilbert seated in the front row, third from the left), none of them appears to be as short as four letters.

Comment: Where did you find a copy of the 1902 portrait with the names at the bottom? In the portrait I found via a Google image search I think I have recognized D. Hilbert, F. Klein, and H. Minkowski...

Comment: Google shows me this as part of the thumbnail it produces when I enter the stated search terms and select [image results](https://www.google.com/search?q=G%C3%B6ttingen+Mathematische+Gesellschaft+1902&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxnYOrvcf2AhXpIDQIHVGZB88Q_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1600&bih=728&dpr=1). FWIW, in the 1902 group portrait I am pretty sure Klein is the person seated to the right of Hilbert (so front row, 4th from left). Above the picture the title "Mathematische Gesellschaft 1902", below it the names of the people depicted arranged in three rows.

Comment: I think we can also find C.-J. de la Vallée Poussin in the 1902 portrait...

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98548/in-search-of-an-early-picture-of-max-dehn